# Javascript sequential functions that return promises

Tags: javascript, arrays, animation, promise

I need to run functions sequentially in order to animate in the proper order, but I am running into some issues. The code basically checks some conditions and stores values in arrays (not shown). These values are passed as parameters to certain functions, which need to run sequentially. I am using promises to achieve this

This code stores the needed functions (and their parameters) in an array `func_call`

```
var func_call = [];
for (var i = 0; i < s_list.length; i++){
    //lower
    if (!isUpper) {
        canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    //upper
    } else {
        canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvasUpr");
        context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    }
    func_call.push(function () {get_path(context, s_list[i], d_list[i], final_arr);});
    func_call.push(function () {draw_marker(context, s_list[i], d_list[i], isFirst[i], isLast[i]);});
}
func_call.push(function() {wrap(final_arr)});
func_call.reduce((cur, next) => cur.then(next()), Promise.resolve());
```

get_path is here

```
function get_path(context, source, desti, arr){
return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    var starting_points = string_to_point[source];
    var ending_points = string_to_point[desti];
    console.log("get path");
    console.log(starting_points);
    /*
    *   Define the variables
    *       i -> iterator count
    *       seg_1 -> points of starting exhibit and closest point on the path
    *       seg_2 -> points of ending exhibit and closest point on path
    *       main_path -> the points along the main path
    *       reverse_flag -> denotes whether the direction is forward or reverse 
    */
    var i;
    var seg_1 = [];
    var seg_2 = [];
    var main_path = [];
    var secondary_path = [];
    var reverse_flag = false;
    var secondary_flag = false;
    var primary_flag = false;
    var starting_point = starting_points[0];
    var ending_point = ending_points[0];
    var vertices = [];
    var pre = [];
    var secondary_vertices = [];
    var points = [];
    var secondary_points = [];

    /*
    *   Add the first two segments
    */
    if(starting_points.length == 3){
        for(var j = starting_points[0]; j <= starting_points[1]; j++){
            seg_1.push({x:point_coord[j][0] , y:point_coord[j][1]});
        }
        starting_point = starting_points[2];
    }
    if(ending_points.length == 3){
        for(var j = ending_points[0]; j <= ending_points[1]; j++){
            seg_2.push({x:point_coord[j][0] , y:point_coord[j][1]});
        }
        ending_point = ending_points[2];
    }
    if(starting_point == 260 && ending_point == 260){
        ending_point = -1;
    } else if (starting_point == 260){
        for(var j = 260; j <= 267; j++){
            seg_1.push({x:point_coord[j][0] , y:point_coord[j][1]});
        }
        starting_point = 72;
    } else if (ending_point == 260){
        for(var j = 260; j <= 267; j++){
            seg_2.push({x:point_coord[j][0] , y:point_coord[j][1]});
        }
        ending_point = 72;
    }


    /*
    *   Handles reverse direction. Switches starting and end points and sets the reverse_flag
    */
    if (ending_point != -1 && starting_point > ending_point){
        temp = starting_point;
        starting_point = ending_point;
        ending_point = temp;

        reverse_flag = true;
    }

    /*
    *   Add points to main_path
    */
    for (i = starting_point; i <= ending_point; i++){
        var b = point_coord[i];
        /*if(i >= 122){
            secondary_flag = true;
            secondary_path.push({x:b[0],y:b[1]});
        } else {
            primary_flag = true;
            main_path.push({x:b[0],y:b[1]});
        }*/
        primary_flag = true;
        main_path.push({x:b[0] , y:b[1]});
    }

    /*
    *   Creates the full path -> combination of seg_1, seg_2, and main_path
    */
    if(reverse_flag){
        if(primary_flag){
            if(secondary_flag){
                vertices = seg_1.concat(secondary_path.reverse());
                secondary_vertices = main_path.reverse().concat(seg_2);

                context.beginPath()
                context.arc(pathways[121][0], pathways[121][1], 8, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
                context.fillStyle = 'green';
                context.fill();

                context.beginPath();
                context.arc(pathways[122][0], pathways[122][1], 6, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
                context.fillStyle = 'red';
                context.fill();
            } else {
                vertices = seg_1.concat(main_path.reverse(),seg_2.reverse());
            }
        } else {
            if(secondary_flag){
                vertices = seg_1.concat(secondary_path.reverse(),seg_2);
            } else {

            }
        }
    } else {
        if(primary_flag){
            if(secondary_flag){
                vertices = seg_1.concat(main_path);
                secondary_vertices = secondary_path.concat(seg_2);

                context.beginPath();
                context.arc(pathways[122][0], pathways[122][1], 8, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
                context.fillStyle = 'green';
                context.fill();

                context.beginPath()
                context.arc(pathways[121][0], pathways[121][1], 6, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
                context.fillStyle = 'red';
                context.fill();
            } else {
                vertices = seg_1.concat(main_path,seg_2.reverse());
            }
        } else {
            if(secondary_flag){
                vertices = seg_1.concat(secondary_path,seg_2);
            } else {
                vertices = seg_1.concat(seg_2);
            }
        }
    }

    /*
    *   Calculate the extra points for animation, and draw the animation
    */
    if(secondary_vertices.length == 0){
        points = calcWaypoints(vertices);
        pre.push(points);
    } else {    
        points = calcWaypoints(vertices);
        secondary_points = calcWaypoints(secondary_vertices);
        pre.push(points, secondary_points);
    }
    arr.push([context,pre]);
    console.log(arr);
    resolve();
});
}
```

`draw_marker` is here

```
function draw_marker(context, source, desti, isFirst, isLast) {
return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    /*
     * Get the point number of the point on the path that the source and destination connect to
     */

    var start = string_to_point[source];
    var finish = string_to_point[desti];

    /*
     *   Marker 
     */
    if (isFirst) {
        var marker1 = new Image();
        marker1.onload = function(){
            marker1._x = point_coord[start[0]][0]-1;
            marker1._y = point_coord[start[0]][1]-44;
            context.drawImage(marker1, marker1._x, marker1._y,marker1.width,marker1.height);
        };
        marker1.src = "images/map_pin.png";
    } else {
        context.fillStyle = 'green';
        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(point_coord[start[0]][0], point_coord[start[0]][1], 8, 0, 2 * Math.PI);

        context.strokeStyle = "green";
        context.stroke();
        context.fill();
    }
    if (isLast) {
        /*var marker2 = new Image();
        marker2.onload = function(){
            marker2._x = point_coord[finish[0]][0]-15;
            marker2._y = point_coord[finish[0]][1]-22;
            context.drawImage(marker2, marker2._x, marker2._y,marker2.width,marker2.height);
        };
        marker2.src = "images/x_marks.png";*/
    } else {
        context.fillStyle = 'red';
        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(point_coord[finish[0]][0], point_coord[finish[0]][1], 6, 0, 2 * Math.PI);

        context.strokeStyle = "#ff0000";
        context.stroke();
        context.fill();
    }
    resolve();
});
}
```

`wrap` is here

```
function wrap(arr){
console.log("in wrap");
var getAnimation = function(context, lines){
    console.log("Get animation");
    console.log(lines);
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        context.beginPath();
        lines.reduce((a, c) => a.then(() => animate(context,c)), Promise.resolve());
        resolve();
    });
};  
arr.reduce((a,c) => a.then(() => getAnimation(c[0],c[1])),Promise.resolve());
}
```

`animate` is here

```
var animate = function(context, p){
return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    console.log("in animate");
    var t = 1;
    context.lineCap = "round";
    context.lineWidth = 5;
    //context.strokeStyle = "#ff0000";
    context.strokeStyle = "#ff3c3c";
    //context.strokeStyle = "#f38f1d";
    var runAnimation = function(){
        if(t<p.length){
            console.log("running animation");
            context.beginPath();
            context.moveTo(p[t-1].x,p[t-1].y);
            context.lineTo(p[t].x,p[t].y);
            context.stroke();
            t++;
            requestAnimationFrame(function(){runAnimation()});
        } else {
            console.log("run animation resolved");
            resolve()
        }
    };
    runAnimation();
});
}
```

The goal is to run however many combos of `get_path` and `draw_markers` as needed, then run `wrap`, which in turn calls `animate`. Each `animate` needs to finish before the next one starts as well

How do I accomplish this?

Thank you. If any more details are needed, please let me know

Comment: I don't understand this 100%. You want to do exactly what? Create an "infinite" `then` chain, so that each function completes before another one starts? What is the problem then? You just keep calling `then` on a promise and problem solved.

Comment: Lets say for example that `s_list` has 2 sources. `d_list` and the other "parameter" arrays will also have 2 elements. With these, I would want to run `get_path`, then `draw_markers`, then `get_path` then `draw_marker` then `wrap`. Each of the calls to `get_path` and `draw_markers` need to have different parameters, for example s_list[0] for one call and s_list[1] for the next

Comment: `somePromise.then(() => { /* select arguments here */ get_path(s_list[0]); }).then(() => { /* ... */ });` If the arguments aren't chosen in a weird way (in which case you would probably have to do it manually), you can automate it via loops or other mechanisms.

Comment: @Whatever Hmm... how would I put it in a loop? I thought `reduce` would accomplish a similar thing

Comment: `func_call.reduce((cur, next) => cur.then(next()), Promise.resolve());` You are calling the `next` function instead of passing it to then. Remove parentheses and the code will (probably) work.

Comment: @Whatever no luck there unfortunately

Comment: So what is wrong then? What happens now? And what errors do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) if the target JavaScript environment supports it. If not you could implement a compiler like Babel and use it that way.

If you don't want to go that route there is Bluebird, a Promise library that allows you to call [`Promise.map`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.map.html) with a `{ concurrency: 1 }` option. This will call the promises in sequential order.

Comment: Is there not a way to do this using the standard promise library? How does async/await work differently, Im new to javascript

Comment: @ChrisM Check out the demo [on the page I linked](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) to understand async/await, it's basically a way to call promises in a synchronous way. I highly recommend checking it out.

Comment: Completely missed the link, checking it out now. It looks like it could be what I need.. If I understand right, an async function is a function that runs, well, asynchronously, and await basically halts execution in that function until the promise on the function called with await returns? In my example, would i need to only create an async function and use a loop to await each function call i need? For example `while(){await get_path(); await draw_marker;}`?

Comment: Exactly! It's very convenient.